# GetStream ios handle response

Tags: swift, getstream-io, moya

I'm calling a method to see if a user is following a specific feed. The code I'm using is:

```
let feed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "public", userId: user.uid)
feed.following(filter: [FeedId(feedSlug: "public", userId: "7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2")], limit: 1) { result in
        print(result)
    }
```

The problem is that I couldn't get the "result". And what I get in the log is:

> Moya_Logger: [13/01/2020 11:08:34] Request:
>   https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/public/55Crx1RIzGasE1p3E1RK8DpWlMm1/follows/?api_key=n9asnsfv92be&filter=public%3A7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2&limit=2&offset=0
>
> Moya_Logger: [13/01/2020 11:08:34] Request Headers: ["Authorization":
>   "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNTVDcngxUkl6R2FzRTFwM0UxUks4RHBXbE1tMSJ9.C8gYvepNOr14qgnXRATA2exBCvNXgmD3pI51OyF_n7U",
>   "X-Stream-Client": "stream-swift-client-2.0.0", "Stream-Auth-Type":
>   "jwt"] Moya_Logger: [13/01/2020 11:08:34] HTTP Request Method: GET
>   Moya_Logger: [13/01/2020 11:08:34] Response:  { URL:
>   https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/feed/public/55Crx1RIzGasE1p3E1RK8DpWlMm1/follows/?api_key=n9asnsfv92be&filter=public%3A7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2&limit=2&offset=0
>   } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
>           "*"
>       );
>       "Cache-Control" =     (
>           "no-cache"
>       );
>       "Content-Encoding" =     (
>           gzip
>       );
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           182
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "application/json;charset=utf-8"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Mon, 13 Jan 2020 16:08:34 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           nginx
>       );
>       "access-control-allow-headers" =     (
>           "x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken, x-stream-client, stream-auth-type"
>       );
>       "access-control-allow-methods" =     (
>           "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
>       );
>       "access-control-max-age" =     (
>           86400
>       );
>       "x-ratelimit-limit" =     (
>           500
>       );
>       "x-ratelimit-remaining" =     (
>           499
>       );
>       "x-ratelimit-reset" =     (
>           1578931740
>       ); } } 
>   {"results":[{"feed_id":"public:55Crx1RIzGasE1p3E1RK8DpWlMm1","target_id":"public:7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2","created_at":"2019-12-20T20:24:59.359562691Z","updated_at":"2019-12-20T20:24:59.359562691Z"}],"duration":"0.89ms"
>   }

I can understand the get request is through Moya and the result is printed in the log. 
So how can I get the result and handle it from the callback in feed.following function?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're keeping a strong reference to the `feed` it shouldn't get deallocated.

This case, `self` will become `nil`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let feed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "public", userId: user.uid)
  feed.following(filter: [FeedId(feedSlug: "public", userId: "7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2")], limit: 1) { result in
    print(result)
  }
}
```

Instead, you need to:

```
let feed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "public", userId: user.uid)
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  feed.following(filter: [FeedId(feedSlug: "public", userId: "7YZSZNpYOMU2GyRcxS1x152loPW2")], limit: 1) { result in
    print(result)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to avoid feed to get deallocated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found "self" is nil in return callback in "Feed+Following.swift".

```
return client.request(endpoint: FeedEndpoint.following(feedId,
                                                       filter: filter,
                                                       offset: offset,
                                                       limit: limit)) { [weak self] result in
                                                            if let self = self {
                                                                result.parse(self.callbackQueue, completion)
                                                            }
    }
```

So what I did is to add `let tmp_self = self` before return, and in the callback, I would use `result.parse(tmp_self.callbackQueue, completion)` to avoid self is nil.

I actually have no idea why self becomes nil in the callback, but this solved my issue.